# Change relative path base for part of an HTML document, especially for injected SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

How can I change the base URL path for only part of a document? Or at least for an SVG section.

In particular, I'm loading an SVG file, and injecting it's contents into the current document (this is done with JavaScript). That SVG is linking to external assets, using relative `xlink:href` attributes. Due to the injection however, that file doesn't know where it was loaded from and resolves paths relative to the document URL. This is why I need to make relative paths in this part of the document relative to the URL the SVG was loaded from.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element, but it will affect the whole document, and there can be only one per doc., so not a good candidate in your case.

The only workaround I see (apart from changing all the URLs) is to inject your svg in their own document, using for instance an `<iframe>`, where you could also inject such a `<base>` element.

```js
const svg = `<svg>
  <image xlink:href="PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" height="150" width="150"/>
</svg>`;
const base = `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/`;

document.querySelector('iframe').srcdoc = `<base href="${base}">
${svg}`;
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

Ps: there **was** an [`xml:base` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xml:base) in svg element, but it's been deprecated and I honestly don't know if any browser ever supported it in an HTML document.